# Unable to insert data into mysql using sprintf

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to find where  I made mistake here: I could not insert data into the database when I use `sprintf` for this particular query while others can!
Is Data type for now() and 0 value correct below?

```
$query2=sprintf("INSERT INTO usrinfo (UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Postcode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,Status,ContactPermissions)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%u','%u','%u','%s','%u','%u')",$unique_id,$name,$phone,$email,$postcode,now(),0,0,0,$gender,0,$permission);
 $insert2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2)or die(mysqli_error($conn))
```

But when I don't use sprintf, it works! Below is the query without `sprintf`

```
$query2="INSERT INTO usrinfo (UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Postcode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,Status,ContactPermissions) VALUES('$unique_id','$name','$phone','$email','$postcode',now(),'0','0','0','$gender','0','$permission')";
```

Comment: can I ask why you're doing it this way? You might wanna look into mysqli's bind_param()

Comment: It must give you an error: you didn't put "now()" as string, and there is no such function in php.

Comment: Can you show any error message?

Comment: no specific reason, just used to it..will look into mysqli's bind_param() also.

Comment: @user4035, its the NOW() function to insert time and date??

Comment: @Jens, the error is on now(), when i enclose it as string, can insert data but value inserted was 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: You **really** shouldn't use string formatting operators to build SQL queries. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead!

Answer (score -1):

There is mismatch of the data type you are defining in your string see below the list of the different params use to define the different data type :--

`%` - a literal percent character. No argument is required.

`b` - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a binary number.

`c` - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as the character with that ASCII value.

`d` - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a (signed) decimal number.

`e` - the argument is treated as scientific notation (e.g. 1.2e+2). The precision specifier stands for the number of digits after the
   decimal point since PHP 5.2.1. In earlier versions, it was taken as
   number of significant digits (one less).

`E` - like %e but uses uppercase letter (e.g. 1.2E+2).

`f` - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).

`F` - the argument is treated as a float, and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware). Available since PHP 4.3.10
   and PHP 5.0.3.

`g` - shorter of %e and %f.

`G` - shorter of %E and %f.

`o` - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as an octal number.

`s` - the argument is treated as and presented as a string.

`u` - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as an unsigned decimal number.

`x` - the argument is treated as an integer and presented as a hexadecimal number (with lowercase letters).

`X` - the argument is treated as an integer and presented as a hexadecimal number (with uppercase letters).

Comment: Dumping a whole amount of stuff from the documentation with most of it not being relevant at all is not a very good answer...

Comment: if you have seen the documentation of above i guess  you would not have get error

Comment: @karvin.developer, I might have gone wrong with it ..Can you tel me the correct data type for now() ?

Comment: Use this `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')` instead of `now()` and keep the data type as `%s` which is there

Comment: @karvin.developer, do I enclose it in string? without it, the query not running!

Comment: ya you can try but this is a purely mysql function which convert the now() value into formatted date string

Comment: @karvin.developer, I'm not sure why but both ways, unable to execute query

Comment: Use the below code . Hope it will solve

`$query2=sprintf("INSERT INTO usrinfo (UUID,Name,Phone,Email,Postcode,DateReg,Reputation,ReviewPlus,ReviewNeg,Sex,Status,ContactPermissions)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',now(),'%u','%u','%u','%s','%u','%u')",$unique_id,$name,$phone,$email,$postcode,0,0,0,$gender,0,$permission);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76511/discussion-between-sweety-and-karvin-developer).